# Run-time User Input Parsing

Tags: c++, parsing, runtime

I'm trying to create a runtime parser that can recognize keywords of a given language or be used for syntax highlighting. I know how to design and implement a simple finite state machine, but the problem is parsing the users input in real time. From a console its simple, I would just call getline() after the user presses enter and iterate through the string, character by character. But in a GUI environment I cant figure out how to parse in real time. For now, I started by creating a simple text box in a metro style app and by triggering a textchanged event I would get the users input, store it into a string, and send it to the lexer for parsing.

```
void InterpreterMetro::MainPage::EditWindow_TextChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
    String ^ input = "";
    input = EditWindow -> Text;

    // Send the string to the lexer for parsing
    m_lexer.Initialize( input )
}
```

Inside my lexer I do the following:

```
void Lexer::Initialize( std::wstring input )
{
    // Store the current input string
    m_input = input;

    // Get the next character in the input
    NextCharacter();

    // Analyze the current input character
    Scan();
}
```

Inside my scan function I have a simple finite state machine implemented by a switch statement

```
Token Lexer::Scan()
{
    State = Initial;

    while( State != Exit )
    {
        switch( State )
        {
            case Initial:
                {
                    if( m_peek == '>' ){ State = Greater; }
                    else{ State = Exit; }
                } break;

            case Greater:
                {
                    NextCharacter();
                    if( m_peek == '='){ State = GreaterEqual; }
                    else{ return m_token.GREATER; }
                } break;

            case GreaterEqual:
                {
                    NextCharacter();
                    return m_token.GREATEREQUAL;
                } break;
        }
    }
}
```

The major problems I'm having are when I call the function NextCharacter() to determine if its a > or >=, the character goes through the switch and bypasses the nextcharacter function because its not waiting for the next input. But I can't figure out how to fix this. Here's my NextCharacter() function:

```
void Lexer::NextCharacter()
{
    std::wstring::iterator iterator = m_input.begin();

    for( iterator; iterator != m_input.end(); ++iterator )
    {
        m_peek = *iterator;
    }
}
```

I've been searching for a solution on how to gather users input in real time and iterate through it for use in a run time parser in a text editor like environment. Everything I find is console based, but GUI based is much different. Can anybody point me in the right direction, in what is the best way to go about this? Is there a better way to get users input in a runtime parser? Am I completely wrong in the way I'm going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I see wrong with your NextCharacter() is that is scans the entire input string, returning the last character always.  You would be better off storing a 'current' iterator in the lexer, and stopping when it reaches the end() of the input string.

In class Lexer:

```
class Lexer
{
   ... your current code...

private:
    std::wstring m_input;
    std::wstring::iterator m_it;
};


Lexer::Lexer()
   : m_input("")
   , m_it(m_input.end())
{
}


void Lexer::Initialize(const std::wstring& input)
{
    m_input = input;
    m_it = m_input.begin();
}

bool Lexer::NextCharacter()
{
    if (m_it != m_input.end())
    {
        m_peek = *m_it++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Something like that. Keep an iterator of the current input along side your input string copy. I hammered this on a web page, so there are bound to be errors, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: That's definitely more efficient, thanks. But I still run into the problem that the nextCharacter function is being bypassed. For example, say the input character was a '>', State Initial sends the character to State Greater, but since the user hasn't typed in another input yet, the current character gets registered as a greater than token instead of waiting to check if the next character is an equal sign. I'm thinking that I need a way to hold the current state, so the next character starts from there instead of the Initial State.

Comment: What you're experiencing is a hitch in the deterministic finite automata of your lexer. Two tokens ('>', '>=') have the same starting sentinel. You can account for this with a a "push_back" (which for you is essentially just a `m_it--` using the sample I provided above, or something similar to that) if the character '=' does not follow '>'. Note: lexers aren't as trivial as people think they are. But at least you have an idea of how to properly walk your input string. The fun is yet to come (skippin whitespace, but only when appropriate =).